# Can I open a bank account before traveling in Istanbul?

Tags: money, turkey, istanbul

When I traveled to Australia, I contacted a bank and opened an account, and transferred money, when I got there, I completed the application form and provided the documents. That was so helpful. But can I do the same in Turkey? Does anyone know a bank that provides this service?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What is your goal?

Comment: To have a bank account ready to go as soon as you land?

Comment: If you have an HSBC Premier account in another country you could ask them about pre-opening an account at HSBC in Turkey, as that is a service they sometimes offer in other countries. I can find no evidence that Turkey is one of the countries where this is possible, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going there myself (Dec 2020), not only was it not possible, but you also had to get a rental utility bill that is issued a month after renting an apartment, in addition to the year-long rental agreement, and a minimum of 1000 lira (not much), to be able to open an account.